# Make every four elements into a single number (element) - python

Tags: python, list, merge, element

So how to the title description?

So the list:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Desired output:

```
[1234,5678]
```

So merge the every four packs of elements!

I am thinking about a list comprehension, but it's not a working well (it is, it's below my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the elements from slicing index of the range, we can do that because of the `step` argument (last one), that make that sequence into an integer (number).

*Note: i am ordering them by rank, so (best on top, and worst at bottom)*

> **Option 1:** [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [int(''.join(map(str,l[i:i+4]))) for i in range(0,len(l),4)]
[1234, 5678]
>>>
```

> **Option 2:** [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html):

```
>>> list(map(lambda i: int(''.join(map(str,l[i:i+4]))),range(0,len(l),4)))
[1234, 5678]
>>>
```

Comment: Note: Option 1 is the better option, both on readability and performance; any time a `map` would require the use of `lambda` that the equivalent listcomp/genexpr can inline, the `map` will be slower. The use of `map` in option 1 is fine (because `str` is an existing function implemented in C which couldn't be avoided in an equivalent listcomp anyway).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes sir, That's how i order them  :-), i know that :D

Answer (score 0):

Assume the length of `l` is the multiple of 4 and each element of `l` is an integer (1 to 9)

Here is another option without using string.

```
[1000*l[4*i]+100*l[4*i+1]+10*l[4*i+2]+l[4*i+3] for i in range(len(l)//4)]
```

Comment: Ouch, Little unreadable, and inefficient..., but thanks for it.

Comment: Note: `range(len(l)/4)` should be `range(len(l)//4)`, use `//` not `/`.